# Modify Datetime function to show right interval

Tags: php, date, datetime

I checked and this is not a duplicate. I have this function

```
$since = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($since));        
        $date = new DateTime($since);
        $interval = $date->diff(new DateTime('now'));
        return $interval->format('%y years, %m months, %d days, %h hours and %i minutos ago %s seconds ago');
```

But of course, I get a date like "5 years, 2 months, 5 days .... "

What I want to get is just one part of the interval. Meaning, I dont want to get "0 years, 0 months, 0 days", but lets say "3 minutes" or "5 days" etc...

I'm new with DateTime but didn't find a function in the php.net site that did that. Is there one or I have to create one by myself? Thanks!

Comment: Not aware of such a function. You'll have to write it yourself.

Comment: why do you use date() and strtotime()? just add $since as DateTime($since) parameter...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I came up with:

```
<?php

/**
 * Return formatted interval where only the largest unit gets displayes.
 * @param DateInterval $interval
 *
 * @return string
 */
function format_properly(DateInterval $interval) {
    if ($interval->y !== 0) {
        return $interval->format("%y years");
    }
    if ($interval->m !== 0) {
        return $interval->format("%m months");
    }
    if ($interval->d !== 0) {
        return $interval->format("%d days");
    }
    if ($interval->h !== 0) {
        return $interval->format("%h hours");
    }
    if ($interval->i !== 0) {
        return $interval->format("%i minutes");
    }
    if ($interval->s !== 0) {
        return $interval->format("%s seconds");
    }
    return "0 seconds";
}

$date = new DateTime("now");
$date->sub(new DateInterval("PT2H5M")); //Now - 2 hours and 5 minutes

$now = new DateTime("now");

$interval = $date->diff($now);

echo format_properly($interval);
var_dump($interval);
```

Answer (score 0):

`DateTime::diff` returns a [`DateInterval`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) instance, whose fields are among the others:

```
public integer $y ;
public integer $m ;
public integer $d ;
public integer $h ;
public integer $i ;
public integer $s ;
```

Just pick the ones you need, e.g. `$interval -> h` for the hours.

EDIT here you have a wrapper:

```
function formatInterval(DateInterval $interval)
{

    static $values = array(
        'y' => 'years',
        'm' => 'months',
        'd' => 'days',
        'h' => 'hours',
        'i' => 'minutes',
        's' => 'seconds',                                   
    );

    $formatString = "";

    foreach($values as $key => $label)
    {

        if(($value = $interval -> {$key}) === 0)
            continue;

        $formatString .= sprintf('%s %s ', $value, $label);

    }

    return  $formatString;

}

$date = new DateTime;
$interval = $date -> diff( new DateTime('2012-09-7'));

echo formatInterval($interval);
```

Prints out:

```
20 hours 47 minutes 13 seconds
```

Comment: Just write a simple wrapper around the values - I'll edit for that.